# Как сместить сразу все элементы?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

День добрый.
Хочу сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку смещались сразу все элементы.
Есть часть кода

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
e.style.left + "30%";
```

Но она не работает.
В консоли выводится что у элемента не определён "left"
Как мне решить это?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых getElementsByTagName возвращает массив элементов, и во-вторых лучше использовать left-padding
типа того:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
e.style.paddingLeft = e.style.paddingLeft+40;
```